# How to figure out someone's seed in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't want to have to deal with terrain when I am rebuilding someone's world on PC Minecraft. They started their world before 1.8 and so I cannot look at F3 to find the seed. Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Run the command '/seed' to find the seed of the world. Sadly you can't copy-paste it though.

Comment: Using /seed then F2 for a screenshot is incredibly useful for this. :)